# Finding intersection between polygons in one shapefile using Shapely

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, intersection, shapely

I'm trying to repair invalid geometries in my shapefile. Before using `object.buffer(0)` method to repair them I need to extract geometries that intersect in-between with their whole surface cause I realized that with buffer method polygons above disappear. Mostly small polygons inside big polygons. How to do this?
WKT:

```
MULTIPOLYGON (((6597172.39 4957989.91,6597180.58 4957982.93,6597193.51 4957997.58,6597185.26 4958004.8,6597185.66 4958005.26,6597199.39 4957993.7,6597200.47 4957992.36,6597204.94 4957975.44,6597203.3 4957967.37,6597210.32 4957966.48,6597207.51 4957963.18,6597187.75 4957964.68,6597188.94 4957968.73,6597184.67624155 4957977.52641856,6597175.69 4957976.97,6597167.43 4957984.01,6597172.39 4957989.91)))
MULTIPOLYGON (((6597197.46 4957992.11,6597199.17 4957990.52,6597196.5 4957987.52,6597194.61 4957989.16,6597197.46 4957992.11)))
MULTIPOLYGON (((6597196.18 4957987.16,6597199.17 4957990.52,6597201.41 4957988.53,6597198.42 4957985.17,6597196.18 4957987.16)))
MULTIPOLYGON (((6597188.47552126 4957983.90502578,6597193.70388783 4957983.55646801,6597193.52960895 4957979.40863053,6597188.33609815 4957980.00117874,6597188.47552126 4957983.90502578)))
```

Polygons disappear after buffer method. So my idea is to extract them and then buffer the rest cause the method works in other situations.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show ho do your polygons look like? Maybe you can provide an example in WKT format?